# Product matching in Python and TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, nlp

I am trying to do a product matching between retail articles from different sellers. They use different names for the same article.
I want to compare the articles from several sellers with the articles that are my database, to know if they are the same. I use the entire name for the comparisons not each word.

I applied this in Python with TensorFlow; with the USE (Universal Sentence Encoder) multilingual (I am working in Spanish language) I obtain the word embeddings for each article and the correlation matrix. Like this I can see the closest articles.

But I would like to use a dictionary for the names of my articles: the key would be the article name of my database, and the values would be different combinations (possibilities) of the description article. I would like to pass this dictionary like input to the model but I don't know how I can do it.

The code to obtain word embeddings:

```
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3"
model = hub.load(module_url)
print ("module %s loaded" % module_url)
model(input)
```

To obtain the heatmap to show the similarities:

```
def plot_similarity(labels, features, rotation):
  corr = np.inner(features, features)
  sns.set(font_scale=1.2)       # Tamaño de la fuente del heatmap.
  plt.subplots(figsize=(30,30))  #Para aumentar el tamaño por defecto del heatmap.
  g = sns.heatmap(
      corr,                     # Datos
      annot=True,               # Muestra el valor numérico de la correlación.
      xticklabels= labels,      # Etiquetas eje X.
      yticklabels= labels,      # Etiquetas eje Y.
      vmin=0.8,                 # Era = 0, aumentamos el valor para que se muestren la progresión de color a partir del 80 %.
      vmax=1,
      cmap="YlOrRd")            # Color del heatmap.
  g.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=rotation)
  g.set_title("Semantic Textual Similarity")
  #Guardamos el gráfico y lo exportamos:
  plt.savefig('Heatmap exported.png', dpi = 400)
  files.download('Heatmap exported.png')

def run_and_plot(messages_):
  message_embeddings_ = embed(messages_)
  plot_similarity(messages_, message_embeddings_, 90)
```

Then I run:

```
run_and_plot(my_list_of_articles)
```

And I obtain the heatmap.

I want to change 'my_list_of_articles' to using a dictionary. In this moment that object is a Python list.

I know I need to train a Neural Network of unstructured text; if I test many combinations of the same articles the NN can learn which article is, but I don't know how to do this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you show any code, you're having a problem with?

Comment: not sure about your question though. Do you want to pass dictionary for your db product info for heat map labels or to your NN model .

Comment: I want to pass a dictionary because each key can contain multiple possibilities of same name, (the values). I think this can be done in a NN but I don't know how. Thank you.

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong  you want to pass dictionary to your neutral network not to heatmap plot . But i don't think we can feed dictionary into Keras or Tensorflow not 100% sure about other DL libraries. Just an idea though you can pass the product name as another feature to your NN model.

Comment: @PrayalankarAshutosh You are right: I want to pass dictionary to the NN; the heatmap only shows the end results.      The thing is that if I pass the product name as  a feature of NN only pass one name per article, (one possible name of each article). I don't know if I am explaining well...

Comment: @PVM any chance you mean embed in run_and_plot def as your NN model. If yes it can be done.

Comment: @PrayalankarAshutosh ok, any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have something like this or create it if you don't have already

```
product_map = { 'product_A' : ['product A description_1' , 'product A description_2'],
                'product_B' : ['product A description_1' , 'product A description_2']}

import numpy as np
def run_and_plot(product_map):
    final_opt={}
    for product in product_map:
        # below expand_dims may or may not be required as most model accept batch size too so you may have to do this
        msg = np.expand_dims(product_map[product]) 
        message_embeddings_ = embed(msg)
        if product in final_opt:
            final_opt[product].append(message_embeddings_)
        else:
            final_opt[product][message_embeddings_]
```

final_opt will be like this

```
{ 'product_A': ['embeddings for description_1 ', 'embeddings for description_2 ' ], 
  'product_B': ['embeddings for description_1 ', 'embeddings for description_2 ' ] }
```

you can plot the similarity of descriptions of each  product individually by

```
for product in final_opt:
    plot_similarity(product, final_opt[product], rotation):
```

Comment: Thank you very much.